# Get all users filtering by custom property using sharepoint search api

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest, search-api

I need get all users with a custom property using sharepoint search api, this custom property already mapped in sharepoint.

I'm using this url, and this retrieves all users

```
http://localsite/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&rowlimit=5&selectproperties='PreferredName,WorkEmail,PictureUrl,Title,Departament,Birthday,Url'
```

But i need get all users with filtering by custom property Birthday, example, Sep/1 to Sep/31

How should I do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a specific date:

```
&refinementfilters='Birthday:datetime("2000-06-25")'
```

For a range (a month in this example)

```
&refinementfilters='Birthday:range(datetime("2000-06-01"), datetime("2000-06-30"))'
```

Comment: I have no idea about this but if your solution is correct then this can be used: &refinementfilters='Birthday:range(datetime("1850-09-01"), datetime("2050-09-31"))'

Answer (score 2):

When using the refinementfilter make sure the Managed Property 'Birthday' is configured as Refineable in the Search schema.

Answer (score 0):

Need to match only date and month. But the above example works fine for exact match including year.

```
&refinementfilter='Birthday:datetime("1970-08-07")'
```

It's retrieving the record of exact match(no different year records like 1978-08-07 are not retrieved)

Answer (score 0):

Using angular js and add this modules SennitShareAngularJs.

Use Example:

```
'use strict';
app.controller('birthDayUsersController', ['$scope', 'sennitRestApi',  function ($scope, sennitRestApi) {

    $scope.birthdays = ([]);

    //Capture all Users birthday of the September
    $scope.birthdays = sennitRestApi.getMonthBirthDayRange('2000-09-01', '2000-09-31');

}]);
```

https://github.com/buenokinder/SennitShareAngularJs